# Eigen values of AB and BA

Tags: linear-algebra, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

let A be a linear transformation from $R^n$ to $R^m$, and B be a linear transformation from $R^m$ to $R^n$, it's easy to show that AB and BA has same eigen-value(except $0$).
But my question is  how to show that the multiplicity of eigen-values are the same? can anyone give a proof just from the theory of linear transformation? I mean, without matrix computation.

Comment: See my answer to http://math.stackexchange.com/a/373271/27978 for example. This is a frequently occurring question.

Comment: Why $A$ and $B$ has same eigenvalue? is there a hypothesis?

Comment: @copper.hat Hi copper, it seems your answers from the link do not involve the multiplicity of eigen-value for which I am asking.

Comment: @Hamou sorry, question edited.

Comment: @annimal: Sorry, I missed that part.

Comment: Not true  unless $n=m$

Comment: It is true even if $n \neq m$. It follows from the fact that if $m<n$, then $\det (\lambda I -AB) = \lambda^{n-m} \det(\lambda I-BA)$, but the OP wants to show this without matrix computation.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Just in case you want the result for geometric multiplicity (dimension of eigenspaces) instead of (or in addition to) algebraic multiplicity, here's a matrix-free proof of that result.

Consider any non-zero eigenvalue $\lambda$ of $AB$ and the corresponding eigenspace $E$.  Also, let $F$ be the eigenspace of $BA$ for the same eigenvalue $\lambda$.  (If you didn't already know that $\lambda$ is an eigenvalue of $BA$, then I'd allow the possibility that $F=\{0\}$; that wouldn't damage the following argument.)  For any $x\in E$, we have $ABx=\lambda x$, and therefore, applying $B$ to both sides, we also have $BABx=\lambda Bx$.  This says that $Bx\in F$.  So we've shown that $B$ maps $E$ into $F$.  Furthermore, this map is injective; non-zero vectors $x\in E$ have non-zero images $Bx\in F$, because $ABx=\lambda x\neq0$.  (This is where we use that $\lambda\neq0$.)  Since we have an injective linear map from $E$ into $F$, it follows that $\dim(E)\leq\dim(F)$.  A symmetrical argument, interchanging the roles of $A$ and $B$) shows that $\dim(F)\leq\dim(E)$.  Therefore the two dimensions are equal.

Comment: got it! thank you so much.

Comment: @Andreas Blass : Nice proof!!! But this is only true for non zero eigenvalues, as in the zero eigenvalue case the statement is not true for even square matrices $A,B$.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a way that uses matrix computations (that works for all $n,m$):

Let $R_1 = \begin{bmatrix} I & 0 \\ -A & I \end{bmatrix} $, $R_2 = \begin{bmatrix} I & -B \\ 0 & I \end{bmatrix}$,
$M=\begin{bmatrix} I & B \\ A & I \end{bmatrix}$.

Note that 
$R_1 M = \begin{bmatrix} I & B \\ 0 & I-AB \end{bmatrix}$,
$R_2 M = \begin{bmatrix} I-BA & 0 \\ A & I \end{bmatrix}$,
and $\det R_k = 1$.

Consequently, we have $\det (I-AB) = \det(I-BA)$ for all appropriately sized $A,B$.

Now suppose $\lambda \neq 0$, and replace $A$ by ${1 \over \lambda } A$, which gives
$\det (I-{1 \over \lambda }AB) = \det(I-{1 \over \lambda }BA)$, or
${1 \over \lambda^m } \det (\lambda I-AB) = {1 \over \lambda^n } \det (\lambda I-BA) $.

Note that $p_{AB}(\lambda)= \det (\lambda I-AB) $ and
$p_{BA}(\lambda)= \det (\lambda I-BA) $ are both polynomials, hence it follows that $(\lambda-\mu)^k$ divides $p_{AB}$ **iff** it divides $P_{BA}$,
and so the non-zero eigenvalues of $AB$ and $BA$ have the same algebraic  multiplicity.

(**Note**: for a truly 'matrix computation-free' proof, one could show that
$\dim \ker (\lambda I-AB)^k = \dim \ker (\lambda I-BA)^k$ for all $\lambda \neq 0$, and $k$, but this is far more tedious.)

Comment: also nice proof, thank you！

Answer (score 0):

If $n=m$: We want to show that characteristic polynomial of $AB=$ the characteristic polynomial of $BA$, i.e $det(AB-xI_n)=\det(BA-xI_n)$

- First case : if $A$ is invertible: 
  $$\det(AB-xI_n)=\det(A(B-xA^{-1}))=\det(A)\det(B-xA^{-1})=\det(B-xA^{-1})\det(A)=\det((B-xA^{-1})A)=\det(BA-xI_n)$$
- Second case: if $A$ is  invertible:
  Let $\{0,\lambda_2,\lambda_3,\ldots,\lambda_r\}$ the eigenvalues of $A$, with 
  $0<|\lambda_1|<\ldots <|\lambda_r|$, now remarking that if$ \alpha\in \Bbb R$  such that $0<\alpha<|\lambda_1|$ the $x$ is not an eigenvalue of $A$ and $A-\alpha I_n$ is invertible, it is easy to show that there is $N\in \Bbb N$ such that for all $p\leq N$, $0<\dfrac{1}{p}<|\lambda_1|$, then for all $p\geq N$, the matrix  $A_p=A-\dfrac{1}{p}I_n$ is invertible. By the first case for all $p\geq N$, $\det(A_pB-xI_n)=\det(BA_p-I_n)$ passing to the limit as $p\to \infty$ (and using the fact that $\det$ is continuous and $A_p\to A$ ) we obtain $\det(AB-xI_n)=\det(BA-xI_n)$.

Comment: nice proof, and what if m $\neq $ n?